# Set Google Map language as Locale language

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I know we can change the language in  map  by using

```
String languageToLoad  = "hi"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

But, this changes the whole map language in "Hindi". How can we change the language based on region language like google maps does[image] 
for every state or country there is different language.
Is there any google api for it or we have add some code at run time?