# android Google Map language as Locale language

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-play-services

[image]As Google-Map App in our phone shows the different languages as per region with English.
I want to implement same in my app also.
But i can not do this in android.
can you please help me to get out of it.

[Set Google Map language as Locale language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328003/set-google-map-language-as-locale-language)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Localization

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

Comment: You have to specify the Locale in your `Android App`, it will handle rest all the things automatically.

Comment: i tried that but it is not work ..can you please give me any refrence link? @AbhinavSuman

Answer (score 3):

Please check this link [What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) for supported language.
&
you can do this by simply changing the Locale of your application like this in your Splash or where you loading the maps.

```
String languageToLoad = "ar"; 
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: In this i can not see  name of the India in Hindi or Gujarati

Comment: you have to set the `Locale` for Hindi and Gujarati if available in supported Language list.

Comment: In place of String languageToLoad = "ar";  i tried both String languageToLoad = "gu"; and String languageToLoad = "guj"; but its not working

Comment: Try with this `gu_ [Gujarati]`
`gu_IN [Gujarati (India)]`, else i have to make a sample to show you as I have used in case of Arabic and its works simply.